# How to read a object from mongodb by spring-data-mongodb polymorphically,from 1.0.4 up to 1.3.1

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, polymorphism

I have one abstract class and one concrete class.

```
abstract class FileModel{
    public abstract void setName();
    public abstract String getName();
}

class Container implements FileModel{
    private String name;
    @override
    public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}
    @override
    public String getName(){return this.name;}
}
```

and my `find` method was like this:

```
public interface ContainerRepository extends
    CrudRepository<Container, String>,
    MongoRepository<Container, String>,
    PagingAndSortingRepository<Container, String> {
    @Query(value = "{ 'pid' : ?0,'status':{'$ne':'deletion'}}", fields = "{'name' : 1,'referenceId' : 1,'_class':1}")
    List<FileModel> findByPid(String pid, Pageable pageable);
}
```

After I run the method `findByPid`,I  got the following error:**No property name found on  FileModel** . Is it necessary to add that property `name` in the abstract class? When back to spring-data-mongodb 1.0.4, all that code above worked fine. Now I just upgraded to 1.3.1, it broke. Anything that can workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After searching on st and some googling. I found some similar questions and did some coding,turns out all I need to do is moving all the `private fields` from the concrete class into the abstract class and make them `protected` except the `@id id`field.Then all things on the go.